# Exec command not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, exec, command-line-interface, shell-exec

I'm using exec to run a **background script** like this :

```
$command = "/usr/local/bin/php public_html/r/index.php tools $action process $params > /dev/null &";
exec($command);
```

The thing is : it's **NOT** working.

**Hints :**

- When I'm executing the very same command from the terminal (via SSH) it's working fine.
- The `exec` command is enabled (I can execute any command without issue).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: What is its output? What is its return value? (Add the [second and third arguments](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to find out.)

Comment: @nickb I'm not getting ANY error; the php script looks as if it's simply not running.

Comment: @Wiseguy It doesn't return **anything**. The second parameter returns an empty array, and the third `0` (=zero).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

background jobs tend to have different 'current' directories than your shell - usually it's the home directory of the account that the job is running under. Unless your public_html is in `/home/whoever`, you're not actually running your script. Try an absolute path:

```
$command = "/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/public_html/r/index.php etc..."
                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

instead.

Comment: Geeeeeez! It worked! Thanks! The funny thing is that my `public_html` **was** under... `/home/whoever`. Setting an absolute path though did the trick! I really can't thank you enough for rescuing me, buddy! :-)